# Efficiently convert two-columns data.table to list

Tags: r, list, data.table

I'm looking for a fast yet readable solution to this problem in R. Preferably the solution should use the `data.table` package or no additional packages although I'd like to hear of other options.

I have a `data.table` with two columns like this one:

```
dat
    go_id gene_id
 1:     A       a
 2:     A       b
 3:     B       c
 4:     B       d
 5:     B       e
 6:     C       f
 7:     C       g
 8:     C       h
 9:     C       i
10:     C       j
```

You can reproduce it with:

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(
    go_id=rep(LETTERS[1:3], times=c(2,3,5))
)
dat[, gene_id := letters[1:nrow(dat)]]
```

I need to convert it to a list where each "key" is a `go_id` with "value" a vector of genes assigned to that `go_id`. That is, the output should be this list:

```
$A
[1] "a" "b"

$B
[1] "c" "d" "e"

$C
[1] "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

If it matters, genes can be associated to multiple `go_id`'s. The real data has about 280000 rows with 17000 distinct go_id's and 16000 distinct genes.

This is the solution I have so far - is there anything better in terms of speed and/or readability?

```
dat <- dat[, list(gene_id=list(gene_id)), by=go_id]
go_ids <- dat$go_id
go_list <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
    go <- go_ids[i]
    genes <- dat[i,]$gene_id
    go_list[go] <- genes
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `data.table` or any other package, this will do the task:

```
tapply(dat$gene_id, dat$go_id, FUN = c)
```

Comment: Bernhard and @sindri_baldur: I knew there ought to be something better than what I did!

Answer (score 3):

```
with(DT, split(gene_id, go_id))
```

Using `by`

```
tmp = DT[, .(.(gene_id)), by = go_id]
setNames(tmp$V1, tmp$go_id)

# $A
# [1] "a" "b"    

# $B
# [1] "c" "d" "e"

# $C
# [1] "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Comment: I'd prefer the above `data.table::split` approach as it is (according to `microbenchmark`) faster than @Bernhard's tapply-approach.

Comment: @ismirsehregal I have no doubt. `data.table` being faster then everything else is normal. I like base functions because they work with traditional data.frames, with tibbles and with data.tables but I also like staying within one paradigm. So it is a coinflip for me. Out of curiosity: how many millisecs is the difference in the given case of "280000 rows with 17000 distinct go_id's and 16000 distinct genes"?

Comment: Btw. we can use `base::split` in the same manner - but as this question is tagged `data.table` I guess that would be the (preferred) paradigm to stay in.

Comment: @Bernhard for the sake of completeness - on my machine the execution time for the tapply approach is 91.6225ms for split it is 56.1975ms using a sample as described by OP.  Also using `base::split` on a `data.frame` is faster than using `tapply` (on the same `data.frame`) - so no need to flip a coin ;-).

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks for sharing. Doing this once, you spare more than 40ms because `split` has a letter less to type than `tapply`. Doing this many times in a simulation, say in Bootstrapping, `split` will be almost twice as fast. I was not aware `split` existed in `base` and even more surprised there is an `base::unsplit`. I am going to seriously investigate where I can use that. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Bernhard thanks for the feedback, glad it (potentially) helps - actually `library(data.table)` only provides a method for `split()` when used on a `data.table` object. Cheers